# elements in array of char* getting corrupted when copied into a new array

Tags: c, arrays, char, allocation

I have come across this before, and the answer has been either to null-terminate the string, or to be sure to allocate enough memory for the string. Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
for (z; z<mountable_volumes; z++)
{
main_items[z] = malloc(strlen(volumes[z])+2);
main_items[z] = volumes[z];
printf("main_items[%i]: %s\n", z, volumes[z]);
}
main_items[z] = NULL;
return main_items;
```

Volumes[] is correct, but when its contents get created into main_items[], it goes bad. I have tried playing with malloc, even outright allocating way more ram than necessary. I have also tried tacking on a '\0' to the end of each main_items[] element. I have tried using strcpy, strncpy, sprintf with the same results.

Here is the log from my program:

```
volumes[0]: Unmount /sdcard
volumes[1]: Mount /system
volumes[2]: Unmount /cache
volumes[3]: Mount /data
volumes[0]: Unmount /sdc)☻
main_items[1]: Mount /syste)☻
main_items[2]: Unmount /cac‼
main_items[3]: Mount /data
```

What am I missing? Thanks! I can paste more of the function if its needed.

EDIT:

here is the entire function: (I have applied the strndup() and free() tips)

```
char** get_mount_menu_options()
{
  Volume * device_volumes = get_device_volumes();
  num_volumes = get_num_volumes();

  char** volumes = malloc (num_volumes * sizeof (char *));

  int mountable_volumes = 0;
  int usb_storage_enabled = is_usb_storage_enabled();

  int i;
  for (i=0; i<num_volumes; i++)
  {
    volumes[i] = "";
    Volume *v = &device_volumes[i];
    char* operation;
if (is_path_mountable(v->mount_point) != -1)
      {   
    if (is_path_mounted(v->mount_point)) operation = "Unmount";
    else operation = "Mount";
    volumes[mountable_volumes] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    printf("volumes[%i]: %s %s\n", mountable_volumes, operation, v->mount_point);
    sprintf(volumes[mountable_volumes], "%s %s", operation, v->mount_point);
    mountable_volumes++;
  }
}

char **main_items = malloc (num_volumes * sizeof (char *));

int z;
for (z=0; z<mountable_volumes; z++)
{     
main_items[z] = strndup(volumes[z], strlen(volumes[z]));
free(volumes[z]);
printf("main_items[%i]: %s\n", z, volumes[z]);
}
main_items[z] = NULL;
return main_items;
}
```

CURRENT LOG:

```
volumes[0]: Unmount /sdcard
volumes[1]: Mount /system
volumes[2]: Unmount /cache
volumes[3]: Mount /data
main_items[0]: Unmount /sdc)☻
main_items[1]: Mount /syste)☻
main_items[2]: Unmount ¿♠
main_items[3]:
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is the type of `main_items`? `main_items[z] = volumes[z];` seems incorrect, you should be using `strncpy`. Arrays cannot be assigned.

Comment: It would be helpful to at least see the declarations of main_items and  volumes.

Comment: entire function has been posted.   main_items is a char** declared elsewhere in the program being created by get_mount_menu_options() (the function I posted):  char** main_items = get_mount_menu_options();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main_items[z] = volumes[z];` should be `strcpy(main_items[z], volumes[z]);`, otherwise the memory that you have allocated on the line just above is leaked, and the pointer `main_items[z]` becomes aliased to the pointer in `volumes[z]`.

Comment: I edited the original question to include the strndup and free tips. I also added the entire function, its not very long anyway :)

Comment: @raidzero You could have an issue in the `sprintf(volumes[mountable_volumes], "%s %s", operation, v->mount_point);`: Are you sure `v->mount_point` is null-terminated?

Comment: I assumed it is since it displays correctly when printing it, but I will try adding a null terminator to the end of it since the problem is obviously not in the bottom for loop :)

Comment: I added a null terminator to v->mount_point: `strcat(v->mount_point, "\0");` but the result is the same

Comment: @raidzero You are calling `volumes[mountable_volumes] = malloc(sizeof(char*));` which is incorrect: it allocates enough space to store a pointer to char, not to store an entire string! It should be `strlen(operation)+strlen(v->mount_point)+2` instead of `sizeof(char*)`.

Answer (score 2):

For copying strings, you need to use the `strcpy()`. Assignments won't work!

```
strcpy(main_items[z], volumes[z]);
```

And moreover,

```
main_items[z] = malloc(strlen(volumes[z])+2);
```

should be

```
main_items[z] = (char *) malloc(strlen(volumes[z]) + 1);
```

And I assume `main_items[z]` and `volumes[z]` is a `char *`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to everyone's examples of `strcpy()`, you can just use `strdup()`, and skip the `malloc()`:

```
main_items[z] = strdup(volumes[z]);
```

Obviously you still have to `free()` your memory! This also relies on `volumes[z]` being NULL-terminated.

**Edit:** Or, as Peter Downs points out in the comments, you can use `strndup()` rather than relying on NULL-termination, if you know the lengths of your strings.

Comment: Or maybe `strndup` if you know the lengths.

Comment: I can get the length of my strings, I will try strndup thanks.